# How to add oninfowindowclick listener to a specific markers?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map that already has markers on it. But I want to add an oninfowindowclick listener only to new markers that I add to the map. How do I do this?

Comment: I think onInfoWindowClickListener set a listener for the map not for the markers, if you want that some markers make some action and some not, i think you should add some validation int the listener, but it will work for the whole map.

Comment: I see. I couldn't think of a way to make validation in the listener for only newly added markers. I was hoping someone could help me with this.

Comment: You're saying are new makers, so as I see this the user is putting the markers, so maybe when you add a marker you can also add an item in a List or ArrayList and then, the validation should be a search in that List.